# How to populate H2 database (or equal embedded db) with data that is provided as individual XMLfiles?

Tags: java, database, junit

I was hoping that I could use predefined set of xml-formated "data sets", and populate test db for each set of junit tests, according to requirements determined by what kind of functionality and features I'm currently testing.

I have found instructions for reading csv files, but I would prefer xml as more readable and easy to reuse and distribute.

Comment: What is your question exactly? How far have you got?

Comment: can you have a simple sql file with inserts instead?

Comment: I can use sql inserts, the motive for xml is plainly human readability, clear "syntax" with attribute - value pairs. I remember having seen a note of a (open source) program or framework that does just that: read xml and (generate sql and) insert data into db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are describing [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: That is it. Thank you very much !

Only I am a bit disappointed at my failure to find it myself with Google search :)